# CakePHP not joining the correct tables in find query

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

OK, another cake question from me.

I have rather a complex table structure with quite a few joins. Here's the jist of it:

[image: table structure]

So, in summary:

```
RiskCategory $hasMany Client   [Client $belongsTo RiskCategory]
Client $hasMany Account        [Account $belongsTo Client]
Account $hasMany Holding       [Holding $belongsTo Account]
```

In my `RiskCategory` model I want to run a query that basically returns the sum of the holdings in each riskCategory id, grouped by date. There's a few other conditions but here is what I've put together:

```
$findParams = array(
    'recursive' => 4,
    'fields' => array(
        'Holding.holding_date',
        'SUM(Holding.value) AS risk_category_value'
        ),
    'group' => array('Holding.holding_date'),
    'order' => 'Holding.holding_date ASC'
    );

$findParams['conditions'] = array(
    'Client.active' => true,
    'Client.model' => true,
    'Client.currency' => 'GBP',
    'OR' => array(
        'Holding.holding_date' => $this->end_date,
        array(
            'Holding.holding_date = LAST_DAY(Holding.holding_date)',
            'MONTH(Holding.holding_date)' => array(3,6,9,12)
            )
        )
    );

$valuations = $this->Client->Account->Holding->find( 'all', $findParams );
```

When I run the above cake is giving me an error saying various fields are not present in the query. The raw query created is as follows:

```
SELECT `Holding`.`holding_date`, 
       Sum(`Holding`.`value`) AS risk_category_value 
FROM   `ips_client_db`.`holdings` AS `Holding` 
       LEFT JOIN `ips_client_db`.`accounts` AS `Account` 
              ON ( `Holding`.`account_id` = `Account`.`id` ) 
       LEFT JOIN `ips_client_db`.`sedols` AS `Sedol` 
              ON ( `Holding`.`sedols_id` = `Sedol`.`id` ) 
WHERE  `client`.`active` = '1' 
       AND `client`.`model` = '1' 
       AND `client`.`currency` = 'GBP' 
       AND ( ( `Holding`.`holding_date` = '2013-10-01' ) 
              OR (( ( `Holding`.`holding_date` = Last_day( 
                      `Holding`.`holding_date`) ) 
                    AND ( Month(`Holding`.`holding_date`) IN ( 3, 6, 9, 12 ) ) ) 
                 ) ) 
GROUP  BY `Holding`.`holding_date` 
ORDER  BY `Holding`.`holding_date` ASC
```

It looks as though cake is not doing all the joins. It is only joining `Account` to `Holding` and then `Holding` to `Sedol` (which is another joined table in the database but is not needed for this query so I've omitted it from the diagram)

Why are the joins not being made properly and how to acheive this? I'd like to avoid writing a raw statement if possible.

EDIT: The joins should be as follows:

```
...
FROM   risk_categories 
   LEFT JOIN ((clients 
               LEFT JOIN accounts 
                      ON clients.id = accounts.client_id) 
              LEFT JOIN holdings 
                     ON accounts.id = holdings.account_id) 
          ON risk_categories.id = clients.risk_category_id 
...
```

Comment: I don't think cake will join `clients` in the first query. Try adding the `account_id` and `sedols_id` to the fields list and see if that helps, but Cake might add clients as an additional query.

Comment: nope, it makes no difference which fields I add, cake returns an error unless the fields are in the tables in the joins

Comment: does Cake return records for Client if you remove the Client from the conditions?

Comment: Yes, I need to remove `Client` from both the conditions and the fields and then the query works.

Comment: okay, that makes sense. I'll post an answer for this.

Answer (score 1):

CakePHP does not perform deep joins for associations that are more than 1 level deep. That is why you're getting an error for references to the `Client` table in the conditions.

For these types of problems it's easier to use the [Containable](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html#containable) behavior. I usually add this behavior to my `AppModel` as the default handler for associations.

Containable allows you to define the associations (only those already defined) with their fields and conditions as part of the find operation. This is done by adding a new `contain` key in the find parameters. Below I've taking a guess at what you might need.

```php
$findParams = array(
    'fields' => array(
        'Holding.holding_date',
        'SUM(Holding.value) AS risk_category_value'
        ),
    'conditions'=>array(
        'OR' => array(
            'Holding.holding_date' => $this->end_date,
            array(
                'Holding.holding_date = LAST_DAY(Holding.holding_date)',
                'MONTH(Holding.holding_date)' => array(3,6,9,12)
                )
            )
    ),
    'group' => array('Holding.holding_date'),
    'order' => 'Holding.holding_date ASC',
    'contain'=>array(
        'Account'=>array(
           'Client'=>array(
                'RiskCategory',
                'conditions'=>array(
                    'Client.active' => true,
                    'Client.model' => true,
                    'Client.currency' => 'GBP',
                )
           )
        )
    )
);

$valuations = $this->Client->Account->Holding->find( 'all', $findParams );
```

Comment: I thought it might be something to do with `containable` but following your suggestion the query that is run is identical to the query before. I removed the conditions and used the `contain` array as in your answer. Also, if I decide to include a field like `Client.risk_category_id` I get the same error as before. It is as if the `contain` array is being ignored.

Comment: Did you add `public $actsAs = array('Containable');` to your `AppModel` class?

Comment: No, but I added it to my `RiskCategory` class which is where I run the query from

Comment: @harryg the behavior has to be in all models used in the query. That's why I always put it in the AppModel.

Comment: OK, it's now in the `AppModel` class but still there is no difference

Comment: @harryg add a `fields` entry for the `contain` options in the find parameters. Add all the fields you need for each association.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Here is my find parameters array: http://pastebin.com/LQ1GKGcY. The `contain` bit is having no effect

Comment: @harryg you are close. You just need to add the other fields and remove the model name: http://pastebin.com/2fDLUhyN

Comment: It gives a result without any errors but the result is wrong. It's still not joining the client table. Here is the query it creates: http://pastebin.com/NaHHyMKQ

Comment: is Account associated with Client in the Account model?

Comment: Yes, Account belongsTo Client and Client hasMany Account

Comment: try adding the fields required by Account to the contain rules. Like you did for Client.

Comment: There aren't any fields required by Account. Is is simply a linking table but the query is not linking it.

Comment: It's only joining holdings to accounts, not account to client and clients to riskcategories